# Missing Resource Type Dropdown in Spinnaker Canary Analysis Stage

Tags: spinnaker

I'm trying to setup Automated Canary Analysis for my application running in an On-Prem Kubernetes cluster using the steps [here](https://ordina-jworks.github.io/cloud/2018/06/01/Automated-Canary-Analysis-using-Spinnaker.html)
. We are using Prometheus for monitoring/metrics.

I'm faced with the following error in the `Canary Analysis` stage when running the pipeline:

```
Either a resource type or a custom filter is required.
```

The issue is that the `Resource Type` dropdown is not available on the `Canary Analysis` form when adding the stage. Based on the screen shots in the [Spinnaker how-to article](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/user/canary/stage/), and in the article above, the `Resource Type` dropdown should be there.

Any idea why is the `Resource Type` not available on the Canary Analysis form? Am I missing some Halyard config?

Here is my Halyard config(with bash variables not shown):

```
hal config version edit --version 1.10.5

echo $MINIO_PWD | hal config storage s3 edit --endpoint http://minio-service.spinnaker.svc.cluster.local:9001/ --bucket data --access-key-id spinnaker-minio --secret-access-key
hal config storage edit --type s3

hal config canary enable
hal config canary prometheus enable
hal config canary prometheus account add $PROMETHEUS_ACCT --base-url http://$PROMETHEUS_URL:9090
hal config canary edit --show-all-configs-enabled false
hal config canary edit --default-metrics-store prometheus
hal config canary edit --default-metrics-account $PROMETHEUS_ACCT

hal config canary aws enable
echo $MINIO_PWD | hal config canary aws account add $AWS_CANARY_ACCT --bucket canary-data --access-key-id spinnaker-minio --endpoint http://minio-service.spinnaker.svc.cluster.local:9001/ --secret-access-key
hal config canary aws edit --s3-enabled=true
hal config canary edit --default-storage-account $AWS_CANARY_ACCT

hal config provider docker-registry enable
hal config provider docker-registry account add $DOCKER_REGISTRY_ACCOUNT --address $DOCKER_REGISTRY_ADDRESS
echo $DOCKER_HUB_PWD | hal config provider docker-registry account edit $DOCKER_REGISTRY_ACCOUNT --username $DOCKER_REGISTRY_ACCOUNT --address $DOCKER_REGISTRY_ADDRESS --add-repository $DOCKER_REGISTRY_REPOSITORY --password

hal config provider kubernetes enable
hal config provider kubernetes account delete k8s-account
hal config provider kubernetes account add k8s-account --context kubernetes-admin@kubernetes --docker-registries $DOCKER_REGISTRY_ACCOUNT --namespaces $K8S_NAMESPACES

hal config deploy edit --type distributed --account-name k8s-account
hal deploy apply
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding a filter template in the metric of the canary config. The canary analysis task was able to run without error after adding this